# Clustered Column Chart Spacing & Width

Tags: powerbi

I have a Clustered Column Chart and I'm having lots of trouble getting a decent display. I have a bunch of teams (Team), each of which has up to five (5) members (Owner). So I drag the Teams field onto the chart and then the Owner field. What I get is the attached (the big red vertical line is my manual add in an image editor, just to split the two teams' columns for this post.

There are a couple of issues with this:

- the columns are so skinny. How can I widen them? I've messed about with the 'Minimum category width', 'Maximum size' and 'Inner padding' but cannot get anything that looks half decent.
- why are the gaps between the columns so irregular? For example, on the attachment to this post, in Team 5, why the large gap between the 642 column and the 305 column? They're both users in the group, the same as the 166 and the 642 columns - so why a different gaps? And how can that be fixed/changed?[image]

Comment: Pretty sure gaps are where you have nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Users' seems to be the field in your legend, correct?  So every team has a 'column' for every user -- regardless if those users are part of the team's membership.  This is why your columns are so skinny.  Every group is packed with every user, and most users have no data in most teams.  The result looks like gaps.

A quick and dirty approach would just create a new field that appends Team Name and User and puts that on your axis instead of the current fields there.  It should solve all these columns with no data.  But, you'll lose drilldown and sorting probably doesn't work quite the way you want either.

Another method would be to add a data column 'Player position' and label each player in a team as 'player 1, player 2, player 3...' so that 'player position' will go into your legend.  That will also get rid of no-data team members, but it will make the columns fairly anonymous.  Maybe put user id on the tooltips.

edit:
Sorry! Probably the most available solution is to use drilldown!  Don't put user in the legend.  Put it on the axis with Teams as a hierarchy, and then use the fork icon to drill down one level on the visual.  Your columns will all have the same color, but you won't have to edit your data model at all, and you'll get more sensible sorting and labeling behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you solve the issue by switching to a 'stacked' bar chart?
The Clustered bar visualization keeps empty space if a certain color is not applicable.